# Edit details in itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Hi Therem Just a quick question. Is it possible to change details about an app that is currently sitting in iTunes connect but with no binary that has been uploaded.

For example I would like to start developing and testing inApp Purchases but the app is not at a stage to have finalised screen shots and a icon etc... So If i create the app id etc and add it to the iTunes store with black images for screenshots can I change that later before approval?

Thanks T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. Most metadata can also be changed beyond the point of AppStore approval.

Editable beyond approval are:

- Description
- (Whats new in this Version)
- Support URL
- Marketing URL
- Privacy Policy URL

Editable before approval are:

- all of the above
- Screenshots

Comment: Thanks Till, Just a little bit stressed that I will use black screenshots etc and be stuck with them haha! Will accept your answer in 10 minutes T

Comment: Can keywords also be changed?

Comment: I can not say for sure about the keywords. They are not changeable as soon as you got approved, thats for sure. Another factor that comes into the equation is if that app has once been approved and if you only plan to supply an update. However, if you never got approved, there is nothing preventing you from creating a new app - just the app-name will have to be changed. So how about you simply start with a fake app that you never plan to release under that name?

Comment: Thats true, but I need to begin allowing inApppurchase packages to be reviewed and sampled in app. However I have now just found that they can only be submitted with the app binary which means I will have to wait untill the app is ready for approval anyway :)

Comment: Narf, right - the chicken egg issue :D ... good luck with your app!

Comment: Keywords can only be changed with a new version of your App. Same with Screenshots.

Comment: I don't quite understand why Apple does not let us change a few metadata even after the app gets approved. To edit a screenshot and a keyword one will have to upload/submit a newer version of the app is difficult to digest. Although, Apple then has its own reasons of piracy and misuse of this feature. So, lets now start submitting our apps with all metadata in place before finally going for approval.

Comment: There may be reasons not to permit keywords to be added for an existing binary, but you also cannot _remove_ them.

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors: you will find Apple's current documentation regarding 'locked' and 'unlocked' iTunes Connect app properties here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html